# Data structure for multidimensional coordinates (search,insert)?

Tags: search, data-structures, insert, coordinates

Is there a data-structure designed specifically for fast insertion and search of multidimensional coordinates (many more than 2 or 3d, for all practical purposes say less than 1k dimensions and 1M points)? Even better, for arbitrary distance metrics?

I know about kd-trees, which are good for insertion, but as far as I know, balancing them is non-trivial, and search is not very efficient in higher dimensions. Unordered maps / hash tables would be a good solution at first glance, but as far as I know there are issues with hashing and collisions (eg converting to a string often truncates the numerical precision, and dealing with collisions of non-neighbouring points can be expensive). Maybe something like a red-black tree on each dimension would be good for insertion, and not too bad for search (recursively filtering along dimensions).

I just don't want to reinvent the wheel and I am sure this is a common need in data sciences these days. Happy to take links to papers / tutorials as an answer. Ideally the answer would have an existing implementation in C / C++ / Python / Java / Matlab.

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail about the actual data you're working with? Maybe provide some concrete examples.

Comment: @JaysonBoubin I am not thinking about any particular data. If it helps to assume the points are in some bounded subspace, or that they are not densely clustered, then these can be working assumptions, but otherwise they are just lists of floats. Did you have something in mind?

Comment: What kind of searching do you need to do? Find all points in a box? Nearest neighbors?

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you're looking for is R-Tree.

You can find Java implementation here.
https://github.com/davidmoten/rtree

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer; however [answers linking to external resources should provide some context](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Would you be able to briefly explain why [R-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) are suitable?